# Security of critical data passing between activities via intent extras

Tags: android, android-activity

I wonder if it is a bad idea to pass **critical data** between application's activities via intent extras.

For example, assume an application have 2 activities: `A` and `B`. Activity `B` will be started by `A` and `A` passes some critical information such as password via an intent extra when starting `B`.

I wonder if this is a dangerous or bad practice in android. For example, can such an approach leak password to other apps? Is there any better way to do so? Generally, do you know any good reference for learning about bad practices in android coding?

Comment: idon't think its bad if you implement proguard in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're referring to intents that just start specific `Activities`, I think you don't need to worry too much.

To take advantage of sensitive information in such intents, attacker will need to do at least one of the following:

1. Find a bug in Android framework that can be exploited
2. Upload custom ROM with malicious additions to user's device without user noticing
3. Upload application APK with malicious additions to user's device without user noticing

While all these scenarios can theoretically happen, I wouldn't bother to safe-guard against them in most cases.